# Spring RabbitListener with RoutingConnectionFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I have set a `SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory` like:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory routingConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory cf1, ConnectionFactory cf2) {
    SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory rcf = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
    Map<Object, ConnectionFactory> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("[foo.server1,bar.server1]", cf1); // receive
    map.put("[foo.server2,bar.server2]", cf2); // receive
    map.put("server1", cf1); // send
    map.put("server2", cf2); // send
    rcf.setTargetConnectionFactories(map);
    rcs.setDefaultConnectionFactory(defaultConnectionFactory());
    return rcf;
}
```

The above `RoutingConnectionFactory` allows me to send messages on specific servers using `SimpleResourceHolder.bind(rabbitTemplate().getConnectionFactory(), host)` as expected, but receiving does not.

I then manually registered a `MessageListenerContainer` that listens on `foo.server1,bar.server1,foo.server2,bar.server2` queues.

I expected to see channel created by `cf1` for the message that was sent to `foo.server1` and channel created by `cf2` for the message sent to `bar.server2` but channel seems to be created by `defaultConnectionFactory`.

But, I can see in my DEBUG log:
`Cannot determine target ConnectionFactory for lookup key [[foo.server1,bar.server1,foo.server2,bar.server2]]`.

This means that `MessageListenerContainer` uses a single `ConnectionFactory` for all queues? Can I somehow configure my listener to use different factory per queue? I tried registering a factory per queue instead of grouping them, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This means that MessageListenerContainer uses a single ConnectionFactory for all queues?

That is correct.

> Can I somehow configure my listener to use different factory per queue? I tried registering a factory per queue instead of grouping them, but that doesn't work either.

No; you need a separate container for each queue. And you might as well bind the real connection factory to it rather than using a routing factory.

Comment: I'll create multiple containers and use MessageChannel to unite the messages... Thanks!